# How can I find my deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, search

Is there a method to search for deleted answers, at least for those that have access to them? Did not see anything under the *Advanced Super Ninja Search Options* on [the Search Options Page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/search).

I don't recall what the question was about, but I know I *answered* it, then later deleted it, as a problem with the solution was pointed out to me. I also remember the user who pointed out the problem in a comment to the now deleted answer.

Is there any way to locate it?

Comment: You should be able to see them on your activity page under you list of answers. Of course, you can only go through by hand.

Comment: @JosephWright: Nope, deleted answers are not listed. I just did a test and answered [my `ensuremath `question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro). It showed up in my answers. I deleted the answer, and then it no longer shows up in my answers...

Comment: I checked on my profile, just in case the rules had changed, but can see my deleted answers there. Can someone else who's not a mod check this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there is no way, see [Can we have an isdeleted:1 search option/operator? on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/can-we-have-an-isdeleted1-search-option-operator).

Comment: Thanks for that link. I think we should still at least be able to locate our own deleted answers since we can see them if we come across them. I guess I'll just start keeping a list when I delete an answer, so I can step through them.